# Attempting to create a database item using the has_one relationship, no exceptions, but still no item

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Models:
A User has_one Ucellar
A Ucellar belongs_to User
I have confirmed from multiple sources that these are set up correctly.  For posterity, here is the top portion of those two models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :authorizations
has_one :ucellar
validates :name, :email, :presence => true
```

This is actually the entire Ucellar model.

```
class Ucellar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Ucellar has a column called user_id, which I know is necessary.  The part of my application that creates a user uses the method create_with_oath.  Below is the entire User class.  Note the second line of the create method.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authorizations
  has_one :ucellar
  validates :name, :email, :presence => true

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @ucellar = @user.create_ucellar
  end

  def add_provider(auth_hash)
    # Check if the provider already exists, so we don't add it twice unless authorizations.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth_hash["provider"], auth_hash["uid"])
    Authorization.create :user => self, :provider => auth_hash["provider"], :uid => auth_hash["uid"]
  end
end

def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  user = User.create({:name => auth["info"]["name"], :email => auth["info"]["email"]})
end

private
  def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
  end


end
```

EDIT:
Forgot to summarize the symptoms.  On create, the user is in the db, with no exceptions thrown, and nothing to signify that anything went wrong.  However, the related ucellar is never created.  Per the documentation [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), the create method should create AND save the related ucellar.

Comment: you have mixed up model and controller code

Comment: @Pavan same symptoms.

Comment: @Santosh  how would I go about unscrewing these?  Much of this was taken from an Oath tutorial, that I followed quite closely.  Should these methods just be transferred directly to the controllers?

Comment: You can move these methods to controller and should be fine, but to be thorough, I think you should go back to the tutorial and verify the code.

Comment: @Santosh, I confirmed that the tutorial had me placing only some of these methods in the model, but not all.  I have moved a few of the methods over to the controller.  I think that this may be an even simpler.  Does the the model.create_association method call the create method of ucellar perhaps?

Comment: Yes, and it expects the association parameters

Comment: I've tried it like this and it doesn't work either.
    `@ucellar = @user.create_ucellar(user_id: @user.id)`

Comment: Do `@user.save` after `@user.new`

Comment: `@user.save` after `@user.new` same symptoms.  Thank you so much for helping!  I'm new, but not that new, and this is very strange.

Comment: also, `@ucellar.save` doesn't affect it either.  I did not expect it to, just covering my bases.

Answer (score 0):

It should create ucellar too.
Try to get the error messages after the creation by calling:

> raise @user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence.inspect

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this wasn't working, but I ended up just moving this code out of the create action of the user controller, and putting it directly after an action that was creating a user.  It solved my issue though.  Thanks everyone for your help!